# How to fix render error when trying to render a map using react native maps with expo on ios?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, render, react-native-maps

I've been following along with different tutorials trying to figure out how to render a map in React Native. I put this together, and in most of the tutorials this seems to do the trick, but for some reason when I try to render it, I get a render error that says:

Render Error Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your componeent from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. Check the render method of 'App'.

It's a one page app so far. Here's the code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { MapView, Permissions, Location } from 'react-native-maps';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      region: null,
    }

    this._getLocationAsync();
  }

  _getLocationAsync = async () => {
    let { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
    if (status !== "granted") {
      console.log("Permission to access location was denied.");
    }

    let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({ enabledHighAccuracy: true });

    let region = {
      latitude: location.coords.latitude,
      longitude: location.coords.longitude,
      latitudeDelta: 0.045,
      longitudeDelta: 0.045
    }
    this.setState({ region: region })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          initialRegion={this.state.region}
          showUserLocation={true}
          rotateEnabled={false}
          showsCompass={true}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff'
  },
});
```

I expected it to work like it was in the tutorials I've been following, but it keeps throwing out the error listed above.